# iOS 8 drag and drop issue in tableview cell

Tags: ios, ios8

I am working on a feature like drag and drop cell in tableview for different rows. I am dragging 1st item to last item and scrolling rows to top of the table view. It is working fine up to iOS 7.1 version, but when I tested the same code base with an iOS 8 beta simulator, the drag buttons disappear are I'm not able to drag the cell anymore. Here is my sample code for your reference.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    list = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", @"9", @"10", @"11", @"12", @"13", @"14", @"15",@"16", nil];    
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [list count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"DragCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
        cell.showsReorderControl = YES;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return  cell;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}

- (BOOL) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath {

    NSInteger sourceRow = sourceIndexPath.row;
    NSInteger destRow = destinationIndexPath.row;
    id object = [list objectAtIndex:sourceRow];

    [list removeObjectAtIndex:sourceRow];
    [list insertObject:object atIndex:destRow];
}
```

Please let me know if you guys have the same issue in iOS 8.

Comment: You should really address this stuff on the Developer forums for iOS 8 beta...

Comment: I am able to drag all the rows in my table view. Although, I have another problem: [Described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24806850/ios-8-editing-tableviewcell-deleting-a-row-removes-the-delete-button?noredirect=1#comment38516059_24806850) When that happens, reorder buttons disappear.

Comment: Nikita, Can you please try to scroll up or down after delete if you have more than 10 rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that. I have a Tableview with Cells wich can be sorted manually. On iOS8b2 there are no reorder Buttons!

Comment: i found out that the reorder controls won't appear if don't have     " -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath"        implemented, even if you don't do anything here!!

Answer (score 0):

i found out that the reorder controls won't appear if don't have

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
```

implemented, even if you don't do anything here!!