# ios 8 editing tableviewcell deleting a row removes the delete button

Tags: uitableview, ios8

While editing my tableview, If I delete a row, the button for delete option disappears. This was working perfectly in iOS7, but now in iOS8, I find this bug.

Is this some Apple bug, or Am I doing something wrong?

Here is an image while editing:
[image: image before]

and this is an image after I delete a row. The `-` button is nowhere to be seen.

[image: image after]

Also, It does not remove the edit mode, only the button disappears

Comment: because it is _beta_, maybe?

Comment: if xcode 6 is beta, this should not work for iOS7 simulators also then?

Comment: you have said it works perfectly in iOS7, the iOS7 SDK is _not_ beta, not even in Xcode6 – but iOS8 is.

Comment: @holex oh okay, so I should wait for the proper xcode relase and check then if this issue is resolved/.?